# WSO2 greg 4.6.0 internationalization

Tags: internationalization, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Is there a way to traduce the user interface of WSO2 Governance Registry ??
I found a properties file for traducing messages prompted by WSO2 but i need to traduce also all the other components (buttons, labels ...)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following links which give an example of localization/internationalization of WSO2 products. This is the same across all the WSO2 products as they share the same Carbon base.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Internationalization+and+Localization

[2] http://tanyamadurapperuma.blogspot.com/2013/10/localizing-wso2-carbon-products-part-1.html

Mifan